# How to drawheat map with large data set in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataset, seaborn

I am trying to plot a sine wave, and the color of the curve at each point is represented by its tangential slope value.
For example, a `3600 * 1000` data frame should be filled:

```
x_axis = list(range(0, 3601))
y_axis = list(range(-1000, 1001))
wave = pd.DataFrame(index = y_axis,columns= x_axis )
for i in range(0, 3601, 1):
    y = int(round(np.sin(np.radians(i / 10)), 3) * 1000)
    wave.loc[y, i] = -abs(y)
wave = wave.fillna(0)
wave[wave == 0] =np.nan
seaborn.heatmap(wave)
```

and by using seaborn.heatmap(wave) the heatmap will be generated like attached image. But what I am looking for is to draw maybe 50-100 sine wave like this in one picture, so the dataframe size will be much larger to 360000*10000. With this size of dataframe I still want to show similar heatmap, or any type or drawing that can represent the value change for each cell. My work station seems to freeze by using seaborn heatmap with this dataset.

Some of my thoughts would be to normalize all the values to `0-255` and use some GLV plotting function, I am still researching it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a similar plot using `plt.scatter`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_axis = np.arange(0, 360, 0.1)
y = np.round(np.sin(np.radians(x_axis)), 3) * 1000
plt.scatter(x_axis, y, c=-np.abs(y), s=1, cmap='gist_heat')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

To get a wider curve, just increase `s`. To get rid of the white part of the colormap, you can move the color limits (called `vmin` and `vmax`). Standard they are the minimum and maximum of the given color values. In this case the maximum is 0 and the minimum is -1000.  Setting `vmax` to +100 would leave out 10% of the color range.

```py
plt.scatter(x_axis, y, c=-np.abs(y), vmax=0.1*y.max(), s=10, cmap='gist_heat')
```

[image: thicker curve]

Comment: Never thought in this way. Looks like pyplot has lots of color options. Thank you for your help so much!!!

Comment: One more question to follow up. If I need to increase the line width -- very wide, and you can expect the lines have some overlay because the line is too wide. For the overlay area, the line color needs to be darker. I want to represent this in the image. I found scatter plot is represented using points, I may still have to go back to choose Dataframe and heatmap. Am I correct? Do you have more suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I really think a heatmap is not suited. You can increase the width of the scatter dots with the `s=1` parameter (`s` is area-like: to double the diameter you need to quadruple `s`). Creating a dataframe is very slow for this application, you could get the same heatmap using numpy arrays (seaborn is happy with them). But such a large heatmap would always be slow and of bad quality. Some trick using the color-limits (vmin and vmax) can help to easily get rid of the white part of the colormap.

Comment: An alternative to a scatter plot, is a plot of line segments as in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html). It is slightly more complicated, but you would get more freedom to increase the line width.

Comment: After I increased the line width to 32, the plot seems very close to what I am looking for. Thanks for helping me solve this:)